# Get client's browser name and ip address using Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, authentication

I'm trying to get a list of all online users. I'm planning to do so, using SpringRegistry. But i also have to get user's browser info and ip address. I know that i could do it in javascript, but i need to retrieve all user's details, not only current one's.

**EDIT**

Here's my code:

```
 @GetMapping("/")
 public String index(HttpServletRequest request){
 String ip=request.getRemoteAddr(); // "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
 return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add **HttpServletRequest** object in your method and get the ip using **getRemoteAddr()** method.No Spring required.Something like this :

```
public void doSomething(HttpServletRequest request){
System.out.print(request.getRemoteAddr()); // Prints ip address 
}
```

Comment: emm... I'm not sure if  this "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" is correct ip address :\

Comment: Man, i found out solution:   
    `if(ip.equalsIgnoreCase("0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1")){
                try {
                    return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }`